# Can you see the balanced tensor product of modules is nonzero from trace?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, ring-theory, tensor-products

Let $A$ be a finite dimensional algebra over the complex numbers and let $R$ and $L$ be finite dimensional right and left modules respectively.  There are complex valued traces defined on $A$ from the associated homomorphisms  of $A$ into the complex linear endomorphisms of $L$ and $R$ followed by taking the trace,
$$ tr_R:A\rightarrow \mathbb{C} \ \mathrm{and} \ tr_L:A\rightarrow \mathbb{C}.$$
If $tr_R=tr_L$ and both are nonzero can we conclude that the balanced tensor product
$$R \otimes_A  L$$ is nonzero?

By the balanced tensor product I mean $R \otimes_{\mathbb{C}} L$ modulo the submodule spanned by all $\alpha a \otimes \beta-\alpha \otimes a \beta$ where $\alpha\otimes \beta$ ranges over $R\otimes_{\mathbb{C}} L$ and $a$ ranges over $A$.

Comment: So you mean... the tensor product?

Comment: Yeah but sometimes people call it the balanced tensor product in the literature.

Comment: Anyway, I think $R$ and $L$ have the same trace iff in their composition series simple modules occur that have the same trace with the same multiplicities. But I don't know what this works out to in terms of the tensor product if $R$ and $L$ aren't semisimple.

Comment: Which brings me back to the last question of mine you responded to. Call those things star algebras, because you can see them by where you place starts in a matrix. If you make the algebra bigger, the tensor product gets smaller. So take the smallest star algebra containing $A$. Work with the tensor product over that algebra. Does it help?

Comment: I think you can draw a graph, there the vertices are the semisimple terms in the jordan decomposition of the column ( or row vector) representation of one of your star algebras. I think the tensor product of the column vector representation with the row vector representation is a direct sum of copies of $\mathbb{C}$, one for each connected component of the graph.  The thing is that $R$ and $L$ here might be more distantly related. I only really care that the tensor product is nonzero.